React Router <Navigate> performing unwanted navigations
I have this code in this if user enters "/movies" path the browser should redirect to "/movies/trending" (this is working), but if the user enters "/movies/popular" the user should see MoviesPopular but it still redirects to "/movies/trending".
<Route
  path="movies"
  element={
    <div>
      <Navigate to="./trending" replace />
      <Outlet></Outlet>
    </div>
  }
>
  <Route index path="trending" element={<MoviesTrending />} />
  <Route path="top_rated" element={<MoviesTopRated />} />
  <Route path="popular" element={<MoviesPopular />} />
</Route>

